# REST API access control extract subject from access token vs. from path parameter

Tags: rest, security, authorization, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

The general idea in securing REST API in OAUTH is by using Authorization Bearer <`access token`> header, typically a JWT, which has information about the subject, ie. `sub: u1`  with u1 is the userId in the database.

With such access token, client app can access the different resources. Let's say an user has many cars, has many boats, etc...So, in RESTful manner, `/users` returns all users, `/users/:u1` returns data of user u1, `/users/:u1/cars/:c1` returns data of the car `c1` of user `u1`, `/users/:u1/boats/:b1` returns data of the boat `b1` of user `u1`, etc.

My question is about `u1`. Shouldn't `u1` be extracted from the JWT access token instead because we know we can trust the JWT? In theory an app can use a JWT issued for user `u1`, but requesting access to `/users/:u2` which should be forbidden.

One can make `/users/:u1` unavailable, and force client app to call `/users` instead and extract the `sub` from the JWT. However, calling `/users` to return data of `u1` breaks the RESTful pattern and its benefits (ie. http caching).

What's the right approach?

This probably an `authorization` framework on REST api question. JWT can only address `authentication` only.

Comment: I believe many server frameworks have guard attributes for REST endpoints.  For example, Microsoft Web API will utilize the 'roles' claim in a JWT which will manifest in the Roles property of the [Authorize] attribute.  So you can lock down specific actions to a role.  You can also create a Policy based on a specific claim and/or claim value in the JWT and also apply it to the [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: it doesn't address the true "source of truth" about the resource owner between the subject in the token (be it policy, role, etc..) vs. the subject in the request param though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO your REST API should be *independent* of your authorization framework.

While it makes sense in your case that user `u1` cannot access cars or boats from user `u2`, this may not hold for all users.

You can easily imagine an administrator user or some other role that does have access to cars and boats of any (or a particular subset of) users.

So, I would say that

```
GET /users/:u1/cars/
```

should responds with `HTTP 200 OK` and return all cars for user `u1` if the user has permission to retrieve the cars for user `u1`. Otherwise it should respond with `HTTP 403 Forbidden`.

So, in other words, use the information from the JWT token to authorize the actions. Do not change your API design to implicitly infer the user context from it.